# Are there any benefits to declaring a commonly declared variable as a global?

Tags: performance, optimization, memory, global-variables

For example, I have:

```
char query[512];
```

declared about 27 times in my application which connects to a mysql database.

The same size each time, and declared in many different functions.

This application will never use threads.

The query is ALWAYS executed immediately after the query is set with snprintf.
There is no function in between the setting and the execution of the query to mess it up.

Are their any benefits or performance gains to declaring this as a global variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely, in terms of memory consumed.  Each object will consume a number of bytes, meaning you could potentially use 27 times less memory for that particular variable.  Additionally, there would be a small amount of overhead for creating those objects.  Overall, this will not make a significant difference, but it is best practice to reuse in this sort of scenario.

Answer (score 2):

Accessing a stack variable is usually equivalent to accessing an offset to a pointer already in a register. Accessing a global variable almost always requires loading the address of the global variable first.

So if you are going to pick nits, use the stack variable. Unless you have other compiler switches turned on that add additional overhead for stack usage.

Of course, it really depends on your specific context (i.e., CPU, programming language, etc.). So it could be either.

Answer (score 1):

I would say there is a benefit in performance, however depending on the size of the application it is potentially negligible but it not optimized.
The reasoning is with a global variable you declare it once right off the bat so the computer knows exactly where it is and all you do is change it. Otherwise, you have to keep re-making it which I imagine is not as fast as if there is always one available.

Answer (score 1):

as i know global varible work like a cache memory which access faster than other variable because it assigned at the start of your program .., if you assign every time a new variable than its just a waste of cpu cycle which just assign the memory to a variable in stack... So use as a global variable